# How to build a dynamic Dojo webapp with dynamic application parts?

Tags: model-view-controller, dojo, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm starting the design of the front-end part of a complex application. If possible, I would like to build it as a Desktop style application, which actually acts as a group of sub-applciations.

For instance, by using Dijit I've prepared a structure layout that will be valid for the whole application, with a left column with a Tree based menu, and a right column where the content is displayed.

By clicking a menu node, the associated Dojo application is loaded and displayed in the right panel. The applciation is made by 2 basic parts: the HTML structure and the JS code. 
What would it be the best way to achieve this? Do you suggest just to use iFrames for the right part (I wouldn't like that much...)? Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a [dijit.layout.ContentPane](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html) in the right part of the layout. It can handle a mix of widgets and HTML contents... no need for iFrames !